# How to write DSL to search out docs that hits the searching word multiple times in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to use DSL to solve the following task:

e.g. docs

```
001   so you think you can dance 
002   how do you like me now
003   I love rock'n roll
...
```

The goal is to use DSL to match the docs with 2 "you" in it, which is doc `001`.

Is it possible to use DSL to make work? OR what else methods can I take if DSL is an dead end?

Comment: I am not sure you can do it. With raw `DSL`, but you should be able to achieve it using painless. (the scripting language of ES)
You can look into https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-filter-context.html or https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-score-context.html

Comment: You can try using [wildcard field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type) and wildcard query.